# What to do with JET_errVersionStoreOutOfMemory on JetUpdate

Tags: database, winapi, extensible-storage-engine

When I call JetUpdate() I sometimes get either JET_errVersionStoreOutOfMemory or JET_errVersionStoreOutOfMemoryAndCleanupTimedOut.

The machine has plenty of free RAM and disk space,  what does this error mean - and more important, what do I do about it?

I've tried actions such as Sleep()ing a bit before retrying the transaction, sometimes this seems to work, but sometimes it doesnt - making me think i'm on the wrong path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to increase the size of the version store (set JET_paramMaxVerPages with JetSetSystemParameter) or do less work inside of one transaction.

As an example of controlling transaction size see the "How Do I Pulse My Transaction?" entry in the documentation: http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowDoI

Comment: The up-to-date link to the doc containing "How Do I Pulse My Transaction" is https://github.com/microsoft/ManagedEsent/blob/master/Documentation/HowDoI.md

I can't edit the answer because I'm getting the "suggested edit queue is full" error.